# Java set values of list of custom object which is a inner class

Tags: java, class

Hi I am facing a problem while trying to set a list of custom class object which is inside another class.

```
public class Request {

  private List<Custom> Custom;

  public List<Request.Custom> getCustom() {
    return Custom;
  }

  public void setCustom(List<Request.Custom> custom) {
    Custom= custom;
  }

public class Custom{

    private String id;

    public String getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setid(String Id) {
        id= Id;
    }
  }
}
```

Now how do I set the id from another class?

Comment: you need an custom object in the other class and from there call the setid() method....

Comment: But how? Can you show me with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following syntax to create object of inner class :

```
classInstance.new InnerClass()
```

Then you can have a list of `Custom` from other class

```
Request req = new Request();
List<Request.Custom> clist = new ArrayList<>();
Request.Custom c;

c = req.new Custom();
c.setid("one");
clist.add(c);

c = req.new Custom();
c.setid("two");
clist.add(c);

req.setCustom(clist);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how do I set the id after that

Comment: I did it in the example I shown in my post @Processor

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it so:

```
Request myR = new Request( );
Request.Custom myCustom = myR.new Custom();
myCustom.setid("17");
```

the trick here is myR.new Custom();
 and this is the consequence because you are using inner/nested classes